# Session lost after redirect_to

Tags: session, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2, koala

I am having problems with the session being lost after a redirect in my application. We are using the gem "Koala" to integrate with Facebook. This gem was working fine with Rails 3.0, but not we have upgraded to Rails 3.2.12 and it's failing because the session vanishes after the redirect to Facebook.

I have been investigating and reading a lot about similar problems, but could not get any solution yet. The key here are 2 actions:

1) Publish_event action, where we set the Koala object and connect with Facebook:

```
def publish_event
   ...
   ...
   callback = url_for(......................)
   @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(Facebook::APP_ID, Facebook::SECRET, callback)
   session[:oauth] = @oauth

   redirect_to @oauth.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => ["offline_access", "publish_stream", "manage_pages"])
end
```

That part works fine and connects to Facebook successfully. Facebook redirects back to our application, and the second action is called:

2) Facebook callback action, where we post the message that we want:

```
def facebook_callback  
  token = session[:oauth].get_access_token(params[:code])
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
  .....
end
```

The problem here is that after the redirection to Facebook, the session is not loaded (Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash:0x30027e4 not yet loaded), so we can not continue, as we need the original oauth Koala object that created the connection with Facebook and that should be in the session.

I have the sessions configured as an active_record_store, and it works well in the rest of the application, so I am very confused here.

Anyone has come across anything similar ? OR do you have any suggestion how to do this differently ?

Thanks !

Comment: Probably, you need to make proper routing for the callback, please show your `rake routes`.